# Mapping letters to integers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The function [arithenco](http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/comm/ref/arithenco.html) needs the input message to be a sequence of positive integers. Hence, I need convert a message into a sequence of numbers message_int, by using the following mapping.

‘A’→1, ‘C’→2, ‘G’→3, ‘T’→4.

Comment: Is this all being done in matlab?  (Why the c++ and html tags?)

Comment: This sounds a bit like homework, too.

Comment: @Årjuné - next time you'd like help with your homework, you need to post how you've attempted to solve the problem. Please put *some* effort into it, because the people who will answer your question certainly will.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, the alphabet you are using contains only four values A,C,G,T (DNA sequences I suppose).

Simple comparison would suffice:

```
seq = 'TGGAGGCCCACAACCATTCCCTCAGCCCAATTGACCGAAAGGGCGCGA';
msg_int = zeros(size(seq));
msg_int(seq=='A') = 1;
msg_int(seq=='C') = 2;
msg_int(seq=='G') = 3;
msg_int(seq=='T') = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oh, just reread your question: your mapping is not so simple.  Sorry.**

(since darvidsOn wrote the same I won't delete this answer - it might give you a start - but it doesn't answer your question completely).

Have a look at http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/ascii-chart.html

You can use `d = double('A')` to convert a `char` into a `double`- you will then need to subtract `64` to get the mapping that you want (because `A` is ascii code 65).

Comment: +1 although I didn't look at your answer, I basically wrote what you wrote in a subsequent edit of my answer, so I'm giving you credit for it :)